# resource file error no culture found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, embedded-resource

i have created a resource file "Resource.resx" in my project and added some values against some keys(string values) now when i try to access the value i get the following error...

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture (or the neutral culture) on disk. baseName: Resource locationInfo:  fileName: Resource.resources

im accessing the resource.resx by following code

```
string key = "Home";
             string resourceValue = string.Empty;
             string resourceFile = "Resource";//name of my resource file Resource.resx

             string filePath =System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

             ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(resourceFile, filePath, null);


             resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(key);
```

im using mvc.net...
plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the class automatically generated by Visual Studio when you added the `Resource.resx` file (Resource.Designer.cs). This way you don't need to write all the code you wrote.

```
// assuming you've added a Home key in the resource file
string resourceValue = Resource.Home;
```

Comment: yes it works that way but i want to get the value dynamically, like i just have to pass the key and retrieve the value...